# SAP BC-IC Excel Interface send format_string

Tags: excel, abap, ole

I'm implementing the SAP BC-IC Interface, for interacting with Excel. This works like expected more or less. But now I face the problem, that I want to set a cell value to 1.1 1.2 1.3 and so on. Excel automatically interprets this as a Date and use the DD.MM Format. How can I avoid this with SAP BC-IC Desktop Office Integration? I think the only method which can help me is this: `set_format_string`. But I don't know how this should look like. Need to format the cell in text-format.

Here is a link to the [official documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_di46c2/helpdata/de/21/b531bce1ba11d2bdbe080009b4534c/frameset.htm) of the `set_format_string` method. Tried `set_range_format` as well which just can format borders, numbers, colors and some stuff, but no text.

Hope some guy out there can help me :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `set_format()` and pass `typ` parameter as 0. Cited from the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_di46c2/helpdata/en/21/b531b9e1ba11d2bdbe080009b4534c/frameset.htm):

> Type for currency formatting:
>
> 0: Display as text

The method call looks like this:

```
CALL METHOD l_iref_spreadsheet->set_format
  EXPORTING
    rangename = 'rangename'
    typ       = 0
    currency  = 'EUR'
  IMPORTING
    retcode   = l_retcode.
```

Comment: works like a charm. Currency sounds so wrong to me in this context that I don't tried this way. But it works. Thank you :)

Comment: It's a mandatory parameter, you have to pass something. It uses for automatic formatting.